# Noisy rear derailleur (Shimano RD-5800)

Tags: derailleur-rear, noise

From the moment of buying the bike from a friend of mine, I have noticed that the rear derailleur was a little bit noisy. I thought that it would be problem solved by cleaning and greasing the jockey wheels.

Unfortunately, I have thoroughly cleaned the rear derailleur and sprayed some teflon lub on its surface. I have also removed and applied teflon grease on the jockey wheels, but the problem continues.

I have uploaded a video of the noise, and notice that it is an aligned chain situation (large chainring and 4th smallest cog). When I go to the 5th smallest cog, the sound gets worse.

This is a photo of the derailleur alignment in the same settings the video was taken:

[image: Derailleur and chain]

Comment: Does it happen with small-big combo (i.e. about 34 front, 21 rear)? My RD-5800 was noisy too in hight gear ratios, changing to RD-9000 did nothing to help. Maybe the issue is in chain and it's angle?

Comment: @Klaster_1 I have tried 36 front, 22 rear combination, and the noise is still present. The intensity is lower, but I would say it is due to reduced chain tension. I think I will try a new chain, if it doesn't work, I may check my hanger alignment or a new rear derailleur.
It is really sad that you still have the problem with a Dura Ace one. Have you checked hanger alignment?
Do you use short or a medium cage one?

Comment: It's not like I'm bothered by it, just curious and looking forward for helpful answers too. Both my derailleurs are short cage.

Comment: I would check the cassette...depending on the rider, sometimes one cog sees more wear and then there will be problems with noise and the shifting. Find out how many miles the bike did before you got it...

Comment: @kellbell I don't think it is the cassette because the noise is present in most cogs. Anyway, I have confirmed with the previous owner, and he did 2000km with this cassette. Which means that, right now, it has about 2200km.

Comment: Adjusting a rear derailleur is always a compromise. Mechanical tolerances will be adding to make it worse and play a part. Borrow a similar wheel with a similar cassette and check. Adjustment will de ideal for one central cog on the cassette, usually the 4th or the 5th but there might be slight misalignments and noise for the others. It can be minimized with some fiddling. After several bikes with mechanical units I switched last year to electronic shifting which can be adjusted to (almost) silent running on all gears, except big-big and small-small.

Comment: Looking at the picture: although it's not taken perfectly from the rear, so it could be an optical illusion, I think I can detect that the cage of the derailleur is angled away from the wheel. They are normally vertical or angled very slightly inwards.

Comment: Check for a bent derailleur hanger. It wouldn't need to be bent much to create a slight misalignment, and noise. The misalignment would change depending on the cog, smaller cogs, more misalignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably due to the combination of  an old derailleur and an old cassette. I have replaced both the derailleur and the cassette, and the noise level has been greatly reduced.

I should also mention that the 105 GS RD derailleur has been replaced by a Ultegra SS. Therefore, the GS may be inherently noisier than the SS.

Alignment of the hanger was checked with alignment tool, but it did not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most of this is included in the comments...  I'd start with derailleur alignment.  Once that's done, you'll need to do some light tuning on the cable tension and limit screws to make up for any changes.  If that doesn't fix it, maybe a new chain would help.  Try borrowing a different wheel(with the same number of gears) to see if it still makes the noise, that will eliminate the cassette and hub body from possibly being the culprit.  I know you're saying it's coming from the derailleur, but it's sometimes difficult to tell when all these parts are so close together.  In the long run, though, if it's noisy, it may just be noisy.  If it's functioning right, it may not be worth messing with.

Answer (score 1):

Having seen the video, it looks like your derailleur is MASSIVELY outside of it's B-tension adjustment. Put it on the biggest cog and turn the B-adjustment screw to the point where the top cog of the derailleur is about 3-4mm away from the cog. In my personal experience, this is a common cause besides the actual indexing, and it looks quite likely here, too.

Also, that chain looks a bit big for an eleven-speed set-up; Is it original? Also check for chain wear, as this will cause a horrifyingly loud sound, along with wearing out the cogs faster.

Also, and this might sound a bit basic, but please bear in mind we have all skill-levels here;
Is the wheel properly aligned within the rear drop-outs? The wheel on the derailleur side needs butting up against the very furthest point of the drop-out, or rather, shoving in as far as it'll go. The drive-side is used to make sure the wheel is A) grabbing onto a safe amount of material and B) to essentially 'zero' the alignment for the cogs, and where they sit inside the frame.

Remember, the adjustment screws on the derailleur only adjust where the derailleur will sit within the frame, not where it'll hit the cogs. You can use the old-style method of measuring the gap between the frame and where the first cog would be, and then measure the distance of the first and last cogs, then adjust the tension of the cable to make it evenly move around the range, and have a perfect derailleur adjustment, you don't actually need the wheel within the frame to do an indexing. However, it is recommended for less experienced to just do it with the wheel on, and it also helps with fine-tuning.

After checking the wheel's alignment, make absolutely certain that the springs on the derailleur are moving easily, with no noise, and without requiring cable tension to be dropped to near zero. They should only need a slight tension adjustment to make a fairly drastic gearing change.

Good luck with the repair!